# how to do 1000 random walks in python with 1000 steps each and take standard deviation and mean of distances travelled

Tags: python, random, standards, mean

how do i make it so I can do for instance 1000 steps for 1000 separate random walks and then take mean and std deviation?  Thanks, sorry for multiple questions.  Somehow I need to have the results come out in a list so i can compute mean and std dev.

```
import random

def randomStep(x,y):
r = random.randint(1,4)
if r == 1:
    x = x + 1
elif r == 2:
    x = x - 1
elif r == 3:
    y = y + 1
else:
    y = y - 1
return [x,y]

x = 0
y = 0

q = input(int("Please input the number of random walks you want to include:"))

t = input(int("please input how many steps you want to include in each random walk:"))
```

Comment: OK, so for the part where you do 1000 walks with 1000 steps each: do you know how to use a for loop?

Comment: To do something many times over, use a loop. To do that task repeatedly, put it in another loop. Look up the concept of "nested loops" for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a loop for this. Just generate all numbers at once, and filter out the number of occurances. This is faster.

```
def nSteps(t):
    steps = numpy.random.random_integers(1, 4, t)
    a,b,c,d = (sum((steps == i)*1) for i in [1,2,3,4])
    x,y = a-b, c-d
    return (x,y)
```

Then, you can get all the `x`, and `y` by iteration:

```
allResults = []
for i in q:
    t = int(input("steps: "))
    allResults.append(nsteps(t))
```

Comment: This looks like a good answer, but I don't think the OP is at the point where they can really benefit from it.

Comment: At this point I am not sure if the OP meant that `t` should vary for each loop. Otherwise the answer is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally we could represent a persons location as a tuple of `x` and `y`, along the lines of:

```
def random_step():
    return T(negative_one_or_one(), negative_one_or_one())
```

We can generate `n` random steps using a list comprehension:

```
def generate_random_steps(n):
    return [random_step() for _ in range(n)]
```

And then we can reduce the random steps over the addition operator to get the equivalent of summing his paths together:

```
def get_coords_from_steps(steps):
    return reduce(add, steps)
```

We can then write a loop that repeats this procedure enough times to get a series of random walks:

```
distances = []
for i in range(1000):
    steps = generate_random_steps(10)
    dist = get_coords_from_steps(steps)
    distances.append(dist)
```

Where `distances` are the random walks. To allow for reducing over addition on tuple to work as expected we must define a class like so:

```
class T(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, args)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return T(*([sum(x) for x in zip(self, other)]))
```

All in all:

```
from random import randint
from operator import add

class T(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, args)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return T(*([sum(x) for x in zip(self, other)]))

def negative_one_or_one():
    return -1 if randint(0,1) == 0 else 1

def random_step():
    return T(negative_one_or_one(), negative_one_or_one())

def generate_random_steps(n):
    return [random_step() for _ in range(n)]

def get_coords_from_steps(steps):
    return reduce(add, steps)

distances = []
for i in range(1000):
    steps = generate_random_steps(10)
    dist = get_coords_from_steps(steps)
    distances.append(dist)

print(distances)
```

You can calculate the variation and stuff from this. I'll leave that to you.